# Get value from dropdown after submit in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I have dropdown list with some universities and in case the user is in a university that isn't in the list he can add it with an input box. My issue is that after the user clicks the submit button I can't get the value from the dropdown.

My code in the view is:

```
echo "University:";
?>
<div id="university2" style="display:block;">
<?php
echo form_dropdown('university2',$this->session->userdata('user'));
echo "&nbsp";
echo "<a href= javascript:ShowContentuni('university')>Other</a>";
?>
</div>
<div id="university" style="display:none;">
<?php
echo form_input('university',$this->input->post('university'));?>
</div>
```

And my code in the controller is:

```
    if(isset($_POST['university']))$university= $this->input->post['university'];
    else if(isset($_POST['university2']))$university=$this->input->post('university2');
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two problems:

- always overriding the value of `$university` with the post value of 'university2', even if it is empty
- the form has two inputs called university, only the second one is being referred to

A quick fix would be to first delete the second 'university' form element, i.e. delete this:

```
echo form_input('university',$this->input->post('university'));
```

Then check that the user if the user has manually entered a university name, and use that if so. If the user did not enter a university name, use whatever the dropdown value is. The code would look like this:

```
$universityFromDropdown = $this->input->post('university');
$universityFromManualInput = $this->input->post('university2');
$university = is_string($universityFromManualInput)
  && strlen($universityFromManualInput) > 1
  ? $universityFromManualInput : $universityFromDropdown;
```

Comment: I don't know if this is part of the issue, but using `$this->session->userdata('user');` to grab a list of universities is not exactly intuitive, better to store it as 'universities' so you know you are pulling a list of universities.

Comment: Are you able to edit your question with the code you have now? I will have another look. I got it working on my computer.

Comment: the code is still the same as I first gave it. didn't have the chance to find the problem.